# Is the representation problem as hard as the discrete logarithm problem?

Tags: discrete-logarithm

I found the assumtion that finding a representation in a cyclic Group G for a randomly chosen value y is as difficult as solving the DL problem.

That assumption was without proof so I am not sure if it is correct. Can someone give a proof or a contradiction?

Comment: Can you spell out what you mean by 'representation'?  Do you mean that there are a small set of group members ${G_0, G_1, ..., G_n}$ and the representation problem is "given $Y$, find a solution in the integers $i_0, i_1, ..., i_n$ s.t. $Y = i_0 G_0 + i_1 G_1 + ...  + i_n G_n$'?